# The weighted average ensemble model does not train on the whole data

Tags: python, keras, data, training, ensemble-learning

I am using custom data generator. I want to apply weighted average ensemble. The training set has 1042 samples, and validation indicates 298 samples. The batch size is 64.

when I run this :

```
member1 = KerasMember(name="model1", keras_model=model_1, train_batches=train_batch, val_batches=val_batch)

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 65ms/step
```

it shows 2/2 and 1/1 which I think is incorrect. and it should be 16/16 for training set.

I checked `train_batch = next(train_aug_gen)`  and `val_batches= next(val_aug_gen)`.
`len(train_aug_gen): 16` and `len(val_aug_gen): 4`
Why `len(train_batch)` is `2` ?!!!

while `train_batch` is:

```
 (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 80, 87, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[[[..........]],
 [[.....]] ,...... 

]]]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        ....
        ....
        [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)>)
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Are you here referring to Keras custom data generator?

Comment: @RandomNerd yes, im using tf.keras.utils.Sequence